# Clarification about running spark jobs on a cluster (AWS)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a HortonWorks cluster running on AWS EC2 machine on which I would like to run a spark job using spark streaming that will swallow the tweets concerning Game of thrones.
Before trying to run it on my cluster I did run it locally.
The code is working, here it is:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{StreamingContext, Seconds}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Twitter_Stream extends App {

  val consumerKey = "hidden"
  val consumerSecret = "hidden"
  val accessToken = "hidden"
  val accessTokenSecret = "hidden"

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GotTweets").setMaster("local[2]")

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

  val myStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("#GoT","#WinterIsHere","#GameOfThrones"))

  val rddTweets = myStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  {
    rdd.take(10).foreach(println)
  })

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

My question are more precisely about this specific code line:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GotTweets").setMaster("local[2]")
```

I replaced the "local[2]" by "spark://ip-address-EC2:7077" which corresponds to one of my ec2 machines but I have a connection failure.
I'm sure that the 7077 port is open on this machine.

Also when I run this code with this configuration (setMaster("local[2]")) on one of my EC2 machine, will my spark use all the machine of the cluster or will it run only on a single machine?

Here the exception:

> 17/07/24 11:53:42 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master
> spark://ip-adress:7077... 17/07/24 11:53:44 WARN
> AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master ip-adress:7077
> java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark://ip-adress:7077  at
> org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
> at
> org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: To have a better understanding of the problem, could you please report the exception output?

Comment: I don't think the exception will bring more information than the ones I've said but I edited my message.

Comment: Can you verify whether you have access to the machine via "telnet ip-address-EC2 7077"

Comment: No I can't access it via telnet. Only with ssh.

Answer (score 1):

To run spark application using `yarn`, you should use `spark-submit` using `--master yarn` . No need to use `setMaster` inside scala source code.

Comment: Not only "no need to use `setMaster`", but rather will-not-work-if-you-include `setMaster`. Have an upvote :)